# Issues while parsing the typing List in python

Tags: python, list, typing

I am facing some issues while debugging this scenario.

**What I want is , I want to copy all the contents of that `return_value` to the `MainInfo` class and return it as a string.**

While doing this I am getting the error as

```
    for (name, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5) in range(12):
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

I will copy the entire code bytes here.

```
class DataEntry(object):

name: str = ''
data1: int = 0
data2: int = 0
data3: int = 0
data4: int = 0
data5: int = 0

def __init__(self,
             name: str,
             data1: int,
             data2: int,
             data3: int,
             data4:int,
             data5: int) -> None:
    super().__init__()
    self.name = name
    self.data1 = data1
    self.data2 = data2
    self.data3 = data3
    self.data4 = data4
    self.data5 = data5

def __str__(self) -> str:
    output_string = f'name: {self.name}\n'
    output_string += f'data1: {self.data1}\n'
    output_string += f'data2: {self.data2}\n'
    output_string += f'data3: {self.data3}\n'
    output_string += f'data4: {self.data4}\n'
    output_string += f'data5: {self.data5}\n'
    return output_string


class DataInfo(object):

    data_entries: List[DataEntry] = []

    def __init__(self, data_entries: List[DataEntry] = None) -> None:
        if data_entries is None:
            data_entries = []
        self.data_entries = data_entries

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        output_string = 'DataInfo:\n'
        output_string += '-'*80
        for entry in self.data_entries:
            output_string += entry
            output_string += '-'*80
        return output_string

class MainInfo(object):

    data_info: DataInfo = None

    def __init__(self,data_info: DataInfo) -> None:
        self.data_info = data_info

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        output_string = self.data_info
        return output_string

def in_a_fun() -> MainInfo:

    return_value= fun()
    print("**** return_values - ",return_value)
    print("**** return_values - ",return_value[0][0][0])
    print("**** return_values - ",return_value[0][0][1])
    print("**** return_values - ",return_value[0][0][2])
    print("**** return_values - ",return_value[0][0][3])
    print("**** return_values - ",return_value[0][0][4])
    print("**** return_values - ",return_value[0][0][5])
    print("**** return_values - ",return_value[0][1][0])
    data_info = DataInfo()
    for (name, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5) in range(12):
        data_entry = DataEntry(name, data1, data2, data3,data4 ,data5)
    data_info.data_entries.append(data_entry)
    return MainInfo{
        data_info=data_info)
```

The console output for these prints are

```
**** return_values - [[('ABCD', 1234, 5678, 1, 1, 1), ('EFGH', 9012, 1314, 1718, 0, 10)]]
**** return_values -   ABCD
**** return_values -   1234
**** return_values -   5678
**** return_values -   1
**** return_values -   1
**** return_values -   1
**** return_values -   EFGH
```

Here I am pasting only two lists. But in actual it may be 12. That's why in the `for-loop` I have mentioned it as `range(12)`

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `range(12)` means, and what do you expect `for (name, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5) in range(12):` to mean? For example, what do you think the value of `name` should be the first time through the loop - and why? How do you expect it to get that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is coming from trying to unpack the first int returned by `range(12)`. What you really want to be doing is something like:

```
for i in range(12):
    # Unpack the data you want for the ith DataEntry
    name, data1, data2, ... = return_value[0][i][0], return_value[0][i][1], return_value[0][i][2], ... 

    # Same as before
    data_entry = DataEntry(name, data1, data2, data3,data4 ,data5)
    data_info.data_entries.append(data_entry)
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. But in your answer you are unpacking it by using only one loop statement.. I think in our case we need to have 2 nested for loops. Am I correct ?

Comment: @VishnuCS could you elaborate on the entries in `return_value`? My solution creates 12 DataEntry objects after unpacking it's values from the i'th list in `return_value`. I didn't fully complete the unpacking line but you should be able to get the idea. You do not need a loop to unpack the values

Comment: `return_values - [[('ABCD', 1234, 5678, 1, 1, 1), ('EFGH', 9012, 1314, 1718, 0, 10)]]`. As of now you can see 2 separate list are there in the `return_value`. Actual use case there will be 12 separate list in this `return_value`

Comment: I did some modification on this and it worked . Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the for (name, data1, etc) in item syntax, Python is expecting that item is an iterable of iterables, which can be unpacked into the variables name, data1, etc. In this case, when you iterate over item, the individual members of item are ints, which cannot be unpacked.

If you want to unpack the items, you need to replace range(12).

Hope this helps!